# Why is there a difference between these two sum commands?

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have a scenario

**where i am calculating the sum of particular column using below two command**

*can any one explain me in detail what actually the command is performing*

**First command [when used to calculate the sum of particular column ]**

```
awk -F '"?\\|"?' '{T+=$(2)*1000} END {printf "%.2f\n",T/1000}' demofile.txt
```

**Second command [when used to calculate the sum of particular column ]**

```
awk -F '"?\\|"?' '{T+=$(2)} END {printf "%.2f\n",T}' demofile.txt
```

when sum calculated using both command is different. why is it so ?

This is the Output :
[image]
This is the file used for calculating [please download and test]
(link removed by moderator, possibly security concern)

Comment: Is it different? Not for me. Show input file and (different) results.

Comment: @RudiC   i will edit the question with demo example

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski   its a great question can look into this issue i will share the demo example give me time i am editing the question

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski edited the question please check

Comment: @RudiC  i have edited the question please check ?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski do u have any command can give me the same solution for both

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski is it machine dependent

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski any other better solution apart from this

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski can you check my file which is shared in question with your command

Comment: I improved my answer.

Comment: @kawenal6962go-mail.com Please add a representative sample of the data to the question itself. Data kept on a remote server may be gone tomorrow, which renders your question useless. Since [there was security concern about the link and the site in your follow-up question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/580167/what-is-better-way-to-sum-floating-values-unix-sum-the-value-up-to-8-to-9-scal?noredirect=1#comment1080070_580167), I have removed the link from this question.

Comment: @Kusalananda, there is no "representative sample" to that problem. You need a huge file, because the error for each sum is **very** little. But to demonstrate the issue, you can just use `yes 0.1 | head -n 10000000`. E.g. `yes 0.1 | head -n 10000000 | awk '{sum+=$1}END{printf "%.5f",sum}'`

Comment: or simply `awk 'BEGIN{printf "%.17f",0.1}'`

Comment: @pLumo It is not a matter of the precision used to output the result. The data loss is in the arithmetic where the total is using 51 bits with a large exponent, and the individual values are using 51 bits with a small exponent. The two sets of 51 bits do not overlap well, the result of an addition needs around 70 bits, and the low 20 bits of the smaller value are discarded. It's 20 bits because we are adding a million values, so at the end the total is about 1e6 times the average value when it gets denormalised to do the addition.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is because of what the [`gawk` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Inexactness-of-computations.html#Inexactness-of-computations) states:

> Binary floating-point representations and arithmetic are inexact. Simple values like `0.1` cannot be precisely represented using binary floating-point numbers, and the limited precision of floating-point numbers means that slight changes in the order of operations or the precision of intermediate storage can change the result. To make matters worse, with arbitrary-precision floating-point arithmetic, you can set the precision before starting a computation, but then you cannot be sure of the number of significant decimal places in the final result.

`gawk` is GNU `awk`. It supports [`-M`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Options.html#index-_002dM-option):

> ```
> -M
> --bignum
> ```
>
> Select arbitrary-precision arithmetic on numbers. This option has no effect if `gawk` is not compiled to use the GNU MPFR and MP libraries.

Your `awk` may or may not be equivalent to `gawk`. In my Debian 9 each of the following two commands yields `25396577843.76`:

```
LC_NUMERIC=C gawk -M -v PREC=60 -F '"?\\|"?' '{T+=$(2)*1000} END {printf "%.2f\n",T/1000}' demofile.txt
LC_NUMERIC=C gawk -M -v PREC=60 -F '"?\\|"?' '{T+=$(2)} END {printf "%.2f\n",T}' demofile.txt
```

Although with `printf "%.4f\n",T` I can still see the difference. Increase `PREC` to get better results.

The underlying problem is explained on this site:
[What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://floating-point-gui.de/)